# BizTalk receive pipeline failing due to disk space

Tags: windows-server-2008, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm doing some performance testing on a BizTalk 2010 installation and one of the tests involves consuming a multi-gigabyte file. I'm receiving an error which is pretty straightforward, but it's missing some key information and I'm not able to figure it out so far based on the documentation.

The error is that the receive pipeline failed; "Reason: there is not enough space on the disk."

Hmmm. Which disk? It could be the partition on which windows is installed, the partition on which BizTalk is installed, the database server, etc. They all seem to have enough space to accomodate the file, but it's going to get much larger as it's transformed to XML, so it could probably be any of them.

I'm looking for suggestions on tracking down the source of the issue so I can get my tests back up and running.

Comment: I've found that there were validation errors in the file; the application event log is full of them. I've also noticed that the temp file on the server running the file adapter is huge (12+GB). Not sure if that's related to the errors or a just symptom of the size of the file I'm trying to process . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably your temp folder that is causing your disk to run full.
When large files are getting processed (especially in mapping or disassemblers), the virtualstream will write parts of the message to disk in order to work in a streaming way and prevent memory leaks.
It is a best practice (especially on production environments) to move the temp folder (the %temp% variable) to another disk than the c:\ drive.  This is where BizTalk is storing all the large message fragments.

From the MSDN help:

> By default, documents that are buffered to the file system during mapping are written to the %temp% directory of the BizTalk Server computer. Change the setting for the %temp% environment variable to a non-system disk to improve performance when buffering large messages to the file system during mapping.

More information can be found here :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560481.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If the error says the disk is full then most likely it is because sql server is running out of disk space.

However, since you mentioned the file sizes are more than gigabytes is size, the error might be likely because the BizTalk server is running out of virtual disk space. This might be because the receive pipeline you are using uses XmlDocument class. XmlDocument class is quite ineffective in terms of memory space since it will usually occupy around 10 times the memory the size of the file. So if you have around 1 GB xml file, using XmlDocument will occupy roughly around 10 GB RAM.

Since you mentioned the file sizes range in 12GB+, it is highly likely that the BizTalk server is running out of RAM memory unless you have memory in the hundreds of GBs. The default for Windows OS when this happens is to store excess data from RAM into a hard disk called virtual disk space. It seems the machine is running out of disk space too - which might explain the error you are getting.

To be sure if you are indeed running out of memory and then subsequently the virtual hard disk space, you might want to profile biztalk server machine for the virtual disk space and/or memory usage. Depending on that investigation you have a few choices in terms of getting to a resolution,

- Increase both the RAM and hard disk space - this might be a quick and easy way to achieve required performance without any code and/or design/architecture refactoring.
- Break the file size - if possible break the file sizes into smaller files.
- Use custom pipeline and pipeline component - You might want to investigate